# My all-in-one printer is randomly making noises when idle

Tags: network-printer, multi-function-printer

I previously owned a Brother all-in-one inkjet printer (DCPJ562DW for what it's worth). I now own a Brother all-in-one laser printer (MFC-L3770CDW). Besides the brand, both are very different machines. Still they have the same behavior of (apparently randomly) making a sound like if they were scanning something, very briefly (like for 2 or 3 seconds), and this several times a day. The apparent randomness of it makes it hard to assess the frequency, but I happened to witness it happening sometimes 5 times a day, while on other days it seems to make it only once or twice or even not make it (even though I assume we've just not been earing it). I was never fast enough to catch any message displayed on the printer's screen when it happens, because it's so fast I would need to be right beside it and be quick enough to look at the screen.  The fact the scanner and/or printer have been used recently or not doesn't seem to impact the behavior one way or another, or at least I haven't noticed a pattern.

One of the computers (on Windows 10) using this printer has brother utilities installed on it, but I've noticed this noise even when that computer was shutdown. Other devices connecting to it are an iMac and a samsung S20+ Smartphone, if that's relevant at all... All connect through WiFi, the printer being available on my private network.

As such, it's no big deal, the device is otherwise working just fine, but still I don't like that kind of mystery left unexplained. Also my printer happens to be in a room where people happen to sleep from time to time, so it can bother them a bit. Does anyone have an idea of what might be happening here, and maybe a possible solution ? (I know, plugging it off would solve it, that's not the kind of solution I'm looking for :-))

Comment: I have the same sort of occasional noise from a HP 477 MFD, and have seen it even on large lasers. I have no definite information on this, but I believe from comments that I have overheard from vendor personnel at my office that this may be simply the printer cycling the image roller to prevent 'burn in' - in a way, you could think of it as a 'screen saver'.

Comment: The HPs will occasionally run a further step which actually lights up the screen & says Calibrating… but yes, the periodic noise is cycling rollers, 'stirring the toner' & generally making sure it's always ready to go when asked.

Comment: Not that it helps.. other than to help you narrow things down.. I too have the same all-in-one inkjet (not the lazer) and it NEVER does this.  Not a peep from that bugger.  I don't connect my mac or phone to it.. just my windows machines (4 of them).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - inkjets just prefer to keep slightly warm, cleverly accelerating the drying of the ink in the nozzles until they jam solid ;) One more reason I swapped to lasers a decade ago, I got entirely sick of running 5 or 6 cleaning sheets before every print job.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I wrote PCL inkjet drivers for over 10 years (over 180 of them).  Many if not most of them park the heads on a sponge and dry out if unused for too long (no heat).  In my job, I had to wipe the jets every morning with hot water to keep them from drying out..  I have never had my DCPJ562DW dry out in the several years I have owned it.  I TOO hate running sheets through.. I can't believe I still dont have a laser. :P

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - I'm an infrequent user for printers, so this was always a major issue. Inkjets drove me bananas  - of course I never cleaned the heads daily or even weekly, just every time i wanted to use it. I swapped to a laser in which the toner lasted 10 years. When it ran out I bought a new printer rather than new toner ;)